# How can I remove a div with a certain class, but leave its content?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm working with a dynamic table row creator in JQuery, and basically, it finds the td and using wrapInner, it wraps the content within the td in a DIV.  After being added to the tbody, the DIV is removed.  Unfortunately, when I have a DIV in the content within the container DIV, it, too is removed.  Is there a way to keep all inner content and just remove the outer DIV tag?

Thanks for your help
Below is the code for adding a table row (I've commented the areas in the function with my attempts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Add new table rows with jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.AniRows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<!--
This first example allows you to add rows and delete rows from the top of the table
-->
Add/Remove - Bottom Row<br />
        <button id="addRowDemo1">Add a row</button>
        <button id="removeRowDemo1">Remove a row</button>
<table id="Demo1" class="rounded-corner"  summary="Anirows Demo 1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">Company</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Q1</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q2">Q2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q3">Q3</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4">Q4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="rounded-foot-left" style="border-right: 0px solid #fff;"><em>This is the footer, notice the plugin skips over it.</em></td>
            <td class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Inatech</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
            <td>40.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CyberCyst</td>
            <td>50.2</td>
            <td>40.63</td>
            <td>45.23</td>
            <td>39.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GlobalGlom</td>
            <td>25.4</td>
            <td>30.2</td>
            <td>33.3</td>
            <td>36.7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MegaSoft</td>
            <td>20.4</td>
            <td>15.6</td>
            <td>22.3</td>
            <td>29.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--
Same thing here except now from bottom, this can be add from top remove from bottom, whatever you like.
-->
Add/Remove - Top Row<br />
        <button id="addRowDemo2">Add a row</button>
        <button id="removeRowDemo2">Remove a row</button>
<table id="Demo2" class="rounded-corner"  summary="Anirows Demo 2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">Company</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Q1</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q2">Q2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q3">Q3</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4">Q4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="rounded-foot-left" style="border-right: 0px solid #fff;"><em>This is the footer, notice the plugin skips over it.</em></td>
            <td class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Inatech</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
            <td>40.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CyberCyst</td>
            <td>50.2</td>
            <td>40.63</td>
            <td>45.23</td>
            <td>39.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GlobalGlom</td>
            <td>25.4</td>
            <td>30.2</td>
            <td>33.3</td>
            <td>36.7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MegaSoft</td>
            <td>20.4</td>
            <td>15.6</td>
            <td>22.3</td>
            <td>29.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--
This demo adds and removes rows that have controls in them...this could be asp.net controls or whatever you wante.
-->
Add row using row with controls<br />

        <button id="addRowDemo3">Add a row</button>
        <button id="removeRowDemo3">Remove a row</button>
<table id="Demo3" class="rounded-corner"  summary="Anirows Demo 1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">Company</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Q1</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q2">Q2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q3">Q3</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4">Q4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="rounded-foot-left" style="border-right: 0px solid #fff;"><em>This is the footer, notice the plugin skips over it.</em></td>
            <td class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Inatech</td>
            <td>20.3</td>
            <td>30.5</td>
            <td>23.5</td>
            <td>40.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CyberCyst</td>
            <td>50.2</td>
            <td>40.63</td>
            <td>45.23</td>
            <td>39.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GlobalGlom</td>
            <td>25.4</td>
            <td>30.2</td>
            <td>33.3</td>
            <td>36.7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "newRow">
            <td>MegaSoft</td>
            <td>20.4</td>
            <td>15.6</td>
            <td>22.3</td>
            <td>29.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#addRowDemo1").click(function () {
                $("#Demo1").addRow({
                    newRow: "<tr><td><div>Scubysoft</div></td><td>30.3</td><td>40.5</td><td>63.5</td><td>42.3</td></tr>"
                });
                $('#Demo1 tr td:not(:last-child)').addClass("rounded");
            });
            $("#removeRowDemo1").click(function () {
                $("#Demo1").removeRow({});
            });


            $('#Demo1 tr td:not(:last-child)').addClass("rounded");
        });
    </script>



(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        rowSpeed: 300,
        newRow: null,
        addTop: true,
        removeTop: true
    };
    var newClasses = "newRow"
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    $.fn.addRow = function (options) {
        opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var $table = $(this);
        var $tableBody = $("tbody", $table);
        var t = $(opts.newRow).find("td").wrapInner("<div style='display:none;' class='tempwrap'/>").parent()
        if (opts.addTop) t.appendTo($tableBody);
        else t.prependTo($tableBody);
        t.attr("class", newClasses).removeAttr("id").show().find("td div").slideDown(options.rowSpeed, function () {
            $(this).each(function (index) {
                                   //alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
//*****************below are the two original lines********************************************
                var $set = jQuery(this);
                $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
//*****************end****************************************************************************
 //*****************here are the lines I've tried (commented out - below)*********************              
                //var $set = jQuery(this).find(".tempwrap");
                //jQuery(this).remove(".tempwrap");
                //var $set = $(this).find(".tempwrap");
                //$set.remove();//
                //$set.replaceWith($set.contents());
 //***************end********************************************************************************              
            }).end()
        })
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Did you try `$set.replaceWith($set.html());`?

Answer (score 2):

You can select the element's content, and use the `.unwrap()` method.

```
$('#your_div').contents().unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sAqGx/

Comment: **+1** for the shortest answer to the longest question.

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks. I felt a little guilty at first for not actually reading 90% of the question, but I got over it. :P

Comment: @gdoron +1 for making me laugh

Comment: @xCRKxTyPHooN. That bastard just added two lines to his answer and ruined my joke. -1. **just kidding**.

Comment: Many thanks - is there a similar way to do this with classes?  Long question - short answer..study in contrasts.  LOL :)

Comment: @buck1112: You're welcome. It shouldn't matter how you select the element. As long as you have a jQuery object with the elements that need to be removed (but contents retained), just do `.contents().unwrap()`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/sAqGx/1/) that does the same, but selects by class.

Comment: As each dynamically generated row will need to be affected, each row will need to have different div id's, but as there is currently no counting mechanism in the structure, a class might work better.  If not, I can always try putting the counter and appending to div id.

Comment: @buck1112: If you wanted to use the `replaceWith` technique, you could pass a function to `.replaceWith()`, and `return $(this).contents()`. http://jsfiddle.net/sAqGx/2/

Comment: Thanks - I'm still experimenting with each approach and will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should take the DIV's parent element, then get the DIV's html content, and after removing it assign the content to the parent. Which I think is done by the `unwrap()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: instead of getting the div parent and then the div, just take the div... =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .html() methods in jQuery? Give this a look, it might help: http://jsfiddle.net/MK5u9/